# Call MVC actionResult with Dropdownlist visual basic

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, drop-down-menu, onchange

I want the dropdownlist to fire a call to the ActionResult after the onChange event, rather than submit the whole form to the server. the idea is, the selected item has to be sent to the server to check is the company selected is available in the database before one can move on to fill the other details. Similarly, when a user types in their name, the onChange should also fire an event to check if the user is available in the database.

index.vbhtml

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Authorise", "Login", FormMethod.Post)
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.SelectedItems, Model.CompanyID, New With {Key .id = "CompanyID"})
</div>
<div>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.UserName, New With {Key .id = "UserName"})
</div>
<div>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.UserPassword, New With {Key .id = "UserPassword"})
</div>
End Using
```

LoginController:

```
Function onChangeCompanyName() As ActionResult
      .... code to check availability of selected value...
    return View()
End Function

Function onChangeUsername() As ActionResult
      .... code to check availability of selected value...
    return View()
End Function
```

LoginModel.cs

```
Public Class LoginModel
    Public Property CompanyID As String
    Public Property LoginErrorMessage As String
    Public Property Username() As String
    Public Property UserPassword() As String
    Public Property SelectedItems As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Public Property Items As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
End Class
```

Any solutions or links to a possible solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you should use ajax in onchange function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a security concern, you can use this
solution to do what you ask for, here are the steps :

- Use JQuery in your index.vbhtml
  to get value from your Dropdownlistfor Client
  then use AJAX to send data by POST

```html
<script>
  function checkMyId(id) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Home/AjaxMethodeCheck",
      data: '{id: "' + id + '" }',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        alert(response.message);
        var value = response.value;
        // do the job ...
      },
      failure: function (response) {
        alert("failure");
      },
      error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
      },
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
      $("#YourDropDownId").change(function () {
        var selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        checkMyId(selected.val());
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

- in your controller you will receive Data and check it
- then send back result on json format to JQuery :

```
    <HttpPost>
    Public Function AjaxMethodeCheck(ByVal id As String) As JsonResult

        Dim Str As String = "Done !"  ' if you want to send back message ...
        Dim value As Integer = 0      ' if you want to send back data ...

        ' Do your job in vb.net

        Dim response = New With {
        .id = id,
        .message = Str,
        .value = value}

        Return Json(response)
    End Function
```

- JQuery to use that result  (ajax success:)